# Show that if $G$ is a simple graph with $p$ vertices, where each vertex has degree$\ge{\frac{1}{2}(p-1)}$, then $G$ must be connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Show that if $G$ is a simple graph with $p$ vertices, where each vertex has degree$\ge{\frac{1}{2}(p-1)}$, then $G$ must be connected.

My professor recommended for me to use contradiction to solve this proof, although I am new to it and unsure of how to solve it through this type of proof method. I attempted to use induction and made little head way, but believe I should try and use contradiction as my professor advised. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It means: assume $G$ is *not* connected, and try to prove that there is a vertex with degree $<\frac12(p-1)$.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to prove that $G$ is connected if and only if $V$ can be partitioned into two nonempty disjoint sets $V_1$, $V_2$ with no edges incident to a vertex in $V_1$ and a vertex in $V_2$.

So, if every vertex has degree at least $\frac 12(p-1)$, then any such partition $(V_1, V_2)$ must have at least $\frac12(p-1)+1$ vertices. Hence $G$ has at least $$2\left(\frac12(p-1)+1\right) = p-1+2 = p+1 $$
vertices, a contradiction.